# Date/Timezone Issue in web service integration

Tags: apex, rest-api, datetime, timezone

I have an apex class making a callout to an external REST API and gets a response as shown below.

```
[
{
    "externalGUID": "0d872ca4-45fc-45f9-97f7-0c4f8068ea79",
    "carrierName": "ABC",
    "effectiveDate": "2020-02-19T00:00:00",
    "endDate": "2020-12-31T00:00:00",
    "renewalDate": null,
}
]
```

The effectiveDate and endDate (datetime fields) are passed as CST times from the external system. However, when I use the apex code to populate the details on the Salesforce Asset object, the effectiveDate and endDate are off by 2 days. If I use it as GMT time, these dates are off by 1 day.

Below is the apex code that I am using to populate the info on Asset object.

```
        template.effectiveDate = (oprResponse.effectiveDate==null)?null:(date.newInstance(oprResponse.effectiveDate.yearGmt(),oprResponse.effectiveDate.monthGmt(),oprResponse.effectiveDate.dayGmt()));
        template.endDate = (oprResponse.endDate==null)?null:(date.newInstance(oprResponse.endDate.yearGmt(),oprResponse.endDate.monthGmt(),oprResponse.endDate.dayGmt()));
        template.renewalDate = (oprResponse.renewalDate==null)?null:(date.newInstance(oprResponse.renewalDate.yearGmt(),oprResponse.renewalDate.monthGmt(),oprResponse.renewalDate.dayGmt()));
```

The template.effectiveDate is populated on the InstallDate in Asset object at a later part of the code.

How do I make sure to integrate the effectiveDate and other dates as CST dates in Salesforce? Can someone help?

Comment: `Timezone` class will help here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_timezone.htm - you can calculate the offset between CST and UTC that is DST-aware and then construct a GMT date

Comment: I know timezone class can be used, but I am not sure how to use in this case. Do I need to use yearGmt(), monthGmt() and dayGmt() as in the OP? Or do I need to use year(), month() and day(). Since the external system is sending the CST date, what will be the value in template.effectiveDate if I use yearGmt(), monthGmt() and dayGmt()? Does this datetime will be in UTC or CST?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume you have an incoming JSON payload that looks like

```
"2020-02-19T14:00:00"
```

when you deserialize this to a variable...

```
 Datetime dt = (Datetime) JSON.deserialize('"2020-02-19T14:00:00"',Datetime.class);
```

the value will be in UTC in Apex and will display as:

```
2020-02-19T14:00:00+0000
```

But the semantic meaning of the input date is that it is Central Time (sadly, the sender is not providing a timezone). So, you need to calculate a new UTC datetime that relies on the offset in minutes between UTC and Central Time

```
Timezone tz = Timezone.getTimeZone('America/Chicago');
Integer offsetMs = tz.getOffset(dt); // offset in milliseconds
Integer offsetMins = offsetMs / (1000 * 60);  // will be -360 for Feb 19 but DST-aware for a datetime in June
Datetime res = dt.addMinutes(-1 * offsetMins);
```

The resulting datetime will be a UTC datetime six hours later than the nominal, deserialized UTC datetime. If you are in Central timezone, and issue this Apex:

```
res.format();  // get datetime in local timezone
```

then it will appear as:

```
2/19/2020, 2:00 PM // which is what you want
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Your solution works perfectly.